# PHP - create dynamic multidimensional file tree array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, tree, filesystems

I want to create a file tree, and for this purpose I need to convert an array of files and directories to a multidimensional file tree array. For example:

```
array
(
   'file.txt',
   'dir1/',
   'dir1/dir2/',
   'dir1/dir2/dir3/',
   'dir1/file.txt',
)
```

to

```
array
(
   'file.txt',
   'dir1' => 
   array
   (
       'dir2' => 
       array
       (
           'dir3' =>
           array(),
       ),
       'file.txt',
    )
)
```

I've tried several functions to accomplish this, but non of them worked. The problem I've encountered for example that there is no easy way to convert an `array ('test','test','test'),'test'` to `$array['test']['test']['test'] = 'test'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a shorter recursive one:

```
function dir_tree($dir) {    
    $files = array_map('basename', glob("$dir/*"));
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
            $return[$file] = dir_tree("$dir/$file");
        } else {
            $return[] = $file;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Been looking for something like this. I'm glad I saw this one before I reinvented the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look to [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889469/creating-filetree-from-full-path-in-php).

The answer is: strtok will save you.

```
<?php

$input = [
'/RootFolder/Folder1/File1.doc',
'/RootFolder/Folder1/SubFolder1/File1.txt',
'/RootFolder/Folder1/SubFolder1/File2.txt',
'/RootFolder/Folder2/SubFolder1/File2.txt',
'/RootFolder/Folder2/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder1/File4.doc',
];

function parseInput($input) {
  $result = array();

  foreach ($input AS $path) {
  $prev = &$result;

  $s = strtok($path, '/');

  while (($next = strtok('/')) !== false) {
    if (!isset($prev[$s])) {
      $prev[$s] = array();
    }

  $prev = &$prev[$s];
  $s = $next;
  }
$prev[] = $s;

unset($prev);
}
return $result;
}

var_dump(parseInput($input));
```

Output :

```
array(1) {
  ["RootFolder"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Folder1"]=>
     array(2) {
       [0]=>
       string(9) "File1.doc"
       ["SubFolder1"]=>
       array(2) {
         [0]=>
    string(9) "File1.txt"
         [1]=>
         string(9) "File2.txt"
       }
     }
     ["Folder2"]=>
     array(1) {
       ["SubFolder1"]=>
       array(2) {
         [0]=>
         string(9) "File2.txt"
         ["SubSubFolder1"]=>
         array(1) {
           [0]=>
           string(9) "File4.doc"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect, been racking my brain all day and this is it! Super!

Answer (score 1):

I have PHP snippet for that:

```
<?php
function wps_glob($dir) {
  foreach (glob($dir . '/*') as $f) {
    if(is_dir($f)) {
      $r[] = array(basename($f) => wps_glob($f));
    }
    else {
      $r[] = basename($f);
    }
  }
  return $r;
}

function wps_files($path) {
  $wpsdir = Array(
     'root' => $path,
     'struktur' =>  wps_glob($path)
  );
  return $wpsdir;
}
?>
```

[example usage here](http://www.denbag.us/2013/10/file-tree-array-php-snippet.html)