# Creating filetree from full path in php

Tags: php, file, tree, directory, treeview

I'm trying to make some kind of file tree from full path strings.

This is what the php-class I use gives me:

```
/RootFolder/Folder1/File1.doc
/RootFolder/Folder1/SubFolder1/File1.txt
/RootFolder/Folder2/SubFolder1/File2.txt
/RootFolder/Folder2/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder1/File4.doc
```

I thought i can make an array like:

```
array 
(
 "RootFolder" => array 
                ("Folder1" => array
                             ("FILE" => "File1.doc"
                              "SubFolder1" => "File1.txt"
                              "SubFolder1" => "File2.txt"                                  
                             )
                 "Folder2" => array
                             (
                              ...
                              )
                 )             
  )
```

To finally get to this result with `<li>` or in a `<table>`:

```
RootFolder/
     |_ Folder1/
     |        |_ SubFolder1/
     |        |           |_ File1.txt
     |        |           |_ File2.txt
     |        |_ File1.doc
     |
     |_ Folder2/
              |_ SubFolder1/
                          |_ SubSubFolder1/
                                         |_ File2.txt
```

I'm stucking on this because i'm a little confused and of course i'm not a dev..

Is there maybe another way to do this? i think i will have about >10 000 file strings to proceed when page is loaded.

**EDIT:**

In fact i have a php object that returns me arrays like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Transmission\Model\File Object
    (
        [name:protected] => RootFolder/Folder1/File1.jpg
        [size:protected] => 13324
        [completed:protected] => 13324
        [client:protected] => 
    )

[1] => Transmission\Model\File Object
    (
        [name:protected] => RootFolder/Folder1/File2.mp3
        [size:protected] => 10383488
        [completed:protected] => 10383488
        [client:protected] => 
    )
[2] ...
)
```

What i want to do is make some kind of file tree table with the name, the size and status of the curent file. I'm based on this http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/phpFileTree/demo/demo_classic.php.

With this object, details can be retrieved with $var->getName(), $var->getsize() and $var->isDone().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strtok` will save you.

```
<?php

$input = [
  '/RootFolder/Folder1/File1.doc',
  '/RootFolder/Folder1/SubFolder1/File1.txt',
  '/RootFolder/Folder1/SubFolder1/File2.txt',
  '/RootFolder/Folder2/SubFolder1/File2.txt',
  '/RootFolder/Folder2/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder1/File4.doc',
];

function parseInput($input) {
  $result = array();

  foreach ($input AS $path) {
    $prev = &$result;

    $s = strtok($path, '/');

    while (($next = strtok('/')) !== false) {
      if (!isset($prev[$s])) {
        $prev[$s] = array();
      }

      $prev = &$prev[$s];
      $s = $next;
    }

    $prev[] = $s;

    unset($prev);
  }

  return $result;
}

var_dump(parseInput($input));
```

Output :

```
array(1) {
  ["RootFolder"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Folder1"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "File1.doc"
      ["SubFolder1"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(9) "File1.txt"
        [1]=>
        string(9) "File2.txt"
      }
    }
    ["Folder2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["SubFolder1"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(9) "File2.txt"
        ["SubSubFolder1"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(9) "File4.doc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the array as easily as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! I let you know if it solves my question. :)

Comment: Great!! it'exactly what i expected, i just have to make a table or similar to get it like i want. Thomas, you're a hero ;)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to tell that i was doing this on an object. I continued my post on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895868/how-to-create-a-filetree-like-table-from-an-object

Comment: Really elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

you can do it  just by pass the path of your root folder to the next function:

```
<?php
$path = 'RootFolder';
ListFolder($path);

    function ListFolder($path){
        //using the opendir function
        $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

        //Leave only the lastest folder name
        $explode = explode("/", $path);
        $dirname = end($explode);

        //display the target folder.
        echo ("<li>$dirname\n");
        echo "<ul>\n";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
            if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                if (is_dir($path."/".$file)){
                    //Display a list of sub folders.
                    ListFolder($path."/".$file);
                }else{
                    //Display a list of files.
                    echo "<li>$file</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</li>\n";

        //closing the directory
        closedir($dir_handle);
    }
?>
```

for more information pls visit [page](http://www.dmxzone.com/go/14199/list-server-folders-and-files-as-tree-with-folder-view-asp-php/)

Comment: @Xatenev : maybe my English not very good but I got that he want to build tree of folders and files, and I make that easy by pass just root folder , he do not need to pas all of folders and files path

Comment: I tryed this earlier but i had heavy load on my servers. I dont want to list my root folder, there are to much items.
It's like listing the "/" on linux servers...

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution

```php
/**
 * Return the complete tree structure representation of the iterator
 * @param RecursiveIteratorIterator $iterator The recursive iterator directory on the path
 */
function buildFullTreeFromPaths(RecursiveIteratorIterator $iterator): array
{
    //Filter dot files
    $iteratorFiltered = new CallbackFilterIterator($iterator, function ($current, $key, $iterator) {
        return !$iterator->isDot();
    });

    $trees = array();
    foreach ($iteratorFiltered as $file) {
        $trees[] = buildTreeFromPath($file->getPathname());
    }
    return array_merge_recursive(...$trees);
}

/**
 * Return the tree for the given path
 * @param string $path 
 * @param array $tree 
 * @return string|array
 */
function buildTreeFromPath(string $path, array $tree = array()): string|array
{
    $pos = strpos($path, '/');

    if (false === $pos)
        return $path;

    $key = substr($path, 0, $pos);

    $tree[$key] = buildTreeFromPath(substr($path, $pos + 1), $tree[$key] = array());

    return $tree;
}

$recursiveIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('RootFolder'), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

//Build the full tree
$tree = buildFullTreeFromPaths($recursiveIterator);
```