# How to create a filetree like table from an object?

Tags: php, html, file, tree, html-table

I was a little bit confused when I made [my first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889469/creating-filetree-from-full-path-in-php). This time I'll be more specific.

I'm trying to make a "filetree-like" table from an object ([From a php-transmission project](https://github.com/kleiram/transmission-php)). In my table I would have the filename, the size and the status (done or not). In the "Name" we can see some kind of "full path to file" string.

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1767861/thomas-ruiz) helped me out of making an array of names, but I forgot telling him that I was trying to grab it from an object..

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<?php
$transmission = new Transmission();
$transfer= $transmission->get('26ec249e2669388ff359923702ac0f5c7687d1be');  
$files = $transfer->getFiles();


foreach($files AS $file) 
    {
    var_dump($file->getName()); // RootFolder/Folder1/File1.jpg
    var_dump($file->getSize()); // 10383488
    var_dump($file->isDone());  // True or False

    print_r($file);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
string(59) "RootFolder/Folder1/File1.jpg" 
int(13324) 
bool(true) 
Transmission\Model\File Object
(
    [name:protected] => RootFolder/Folder1/File1.jpg
    [size:protected] => 13324
    [completed:protected] => 13324
    [client:protected] => 
)
```

**$files will output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Transmission\Model\File Object
    (
        [name:protected] => RootFolder/Folder1/File1.jpg
        [size:protected] => 13324
        [completed:protected] => 13324
        [client:protected] => 
    )

[1] => Transmission\Model\File Object
    (
        [name:protected] => RootFolder/Folder1/File2.mp3
        [size:protected] => 10383488
        [completed:protected] => 10383488
        [client:protected] => 
    )
[2] ...
)
```

I saw a nice work from [www.abeautifulsite.net](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2007/06/php-file-tree/), but it's based on `is_dir()` command.

What I want to do is a html table with collapsible parts (on folders) and files info (name, size and status) on file rows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of the first part of my problem. Here's my code (based on my old post):

```
function createArray ($filesObject)
  {
  $result = array();
  foreach($filesObject AS $file) 
    {
    $prev = &$result;
    $s = strtok($file->getName(), '/');

     while (($next = strtok('/')) !== false) 
        {
        if (!isset($prev[$s])) {
        $prev[$s] = array();
        }

        $prev = &$prev[$s];
        $s = $next;
        }

    $prev[] = $s.'|'.$file->getSize().'|'.$file->isDone(); // Delimiter is '|'
    unset($prev);
    }
  return $result;
  }
```

The second part consists in displaying this array in some kind of file tree style html table.
If someone have anny ideas?