# Array of file objects to tree structure

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
Array
(
    [dir1/dir1-1/] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1.pdf
            [size] => 816701
            [type] => pdf
            [date] => 2020-08-27 18:49:24
        )

    [dir1/dir1-1/] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2.pdf
            [size] => 394459
            [type] => pdf
            [date] => 2020-08-17 18:13:43
        )

    [dir1/dir1-2/] => Array
        (
            [name] => name3.pdf
            [size] => 1536144
            [type] => pdf
            [date] => 2020-11-11 12:53:34
        )

    [dir1/dir1-2/dir1-2-1/] => Array
        (
            [name] => name4.pdf
            [size] => 10047255
            [type] => pdf
            [date] => 2021-11-18 12:34:43
        )
    [dir2/dir2-1/] => Array
        (
            [name] => name5.pdf
            [size] => 13419981
            [type] => pdf
            [date] => 2022-03-11 15:13:24
        )
```

Using PHP, I would like to turn a flattened list of file objects, with keys defining their directory structure, into a JSON tree that can used by this finder library:

https://github.com/bu/hColumns

```
let data = [
      {
        content: [
          {
            label: "dir1", 
            type: "folder",
            content: [
              {
                label: "dir1-1",
                type: "folder",
                content: [
                  {
                    label: "name1.pdf",
                    size: 816701,
                    type: "file",
                    date: 2020-08-27 18:49:24

                  },
                  {
                    label: "name2.pdf",
                    size: 394459,
                    type: "file",
                    date: 2020-08-17 18:13:43
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                label: "dir1-2",
                type: "folder",
                content: [
                  {
                    label: "name3.pdf",
                    size: 1536144,
                    type: "file",
                    date: 2020-11-11 12:53:34

                  },
                  {
                    label: "dir1-2-1",
                    type: "folder",
                    content: [
                      {
                        label: "name4.pdf",
                        size: 10047255,
                        type: "file",
                        date: 2021-11-18 12:34:43
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
```

The example uses directory names that somewhat explain the hierarchy, but in my actual use, they'll be somewhat arbitrary.

[Creating filetree from full path in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889469/creating-filetree-from-full-path-in-php)

I started with the solution provided in this post, but it doesn't use file objects, but rather just string endpoints. Has anyone yet modified the solution yet to work in the objects?

Comment: How about turning your file objects to string endpoints?

Comment: You're right, @JunPan .. that was a good idea. It works nicely. I can post the solution here, if you like.

Comment: @Nick You're right. I posted the solution, below.

Comment: Your input data is not a valid PHP array (it has entries with the same key). What is the actual structure?

Answer (score 1):

I modified the solution found here ( [Creating filetree from full path in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889469/creating-filetree-from-full-path-in-php) ) to use two arguments:

1. A list of absolute paths as this (**$paths**):

```
Array
(
    [0] => dir1/name1.pdf
    [1] => dir2/name2.pdf
    [2] => dir2/name3.pdf
    ...
```

2. A list of objects using that path as a key (**$docs**):

```
Array
(
    [dir1/name1.pdf] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1.pdf
            [size] => 816701
            [date] => 2020-08-27 18:49:24
        )

    [dir2/name2.pdf] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2.pdf
            [size] => 394459
            [date] => 2020-08-17 18:13:43
        )

    [dir2/name3.pdf] => Array
        (
            [name] => name3.pdf
            [size] => 1536144
            [date] => 2020-11-11 12:53:34
        )
    ...
```

And that was worked into the original solution:

```
$tree = parseInput($paths,$docs);

function parseInput($input, &$docs) {
  $result = array();
  foreach($input as $path){
    $prev = &$result;
    $s = strtok($path, '/');
    while(($next = strtok('/')) !== false){
        if(!isset($prev[$s])){
            $prev[$s] = array("label" => $s, "type" => "folder");
        }
      $prev = &$prev[$s];
      $s = $next;
    }
    if(!isset($prev['content'])) $prev['content'] = array();
    $prev['content'][] = $docs[$path];
    unset($prev);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Thanks all.