# Build file tree array with PHP and render in VueJS

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a file tree array with PHP based on the data blueprint from `var treeData` from [Tree View - Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html) (visible in javascript tab).

```
var treeData = [
  {
    name: 'My Tree',
    children: [
        { name: 'hello' },
        { name: 'wat' },
        {
            name: 'child folder',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'child folder',
                    children: [
                        { name: 'hello' },
                        { name: 'wat' }
                    ]
                },
                { name: 'hello' },
                { name: 'wat' },
                {
                    name: 'child folder',
                    children: [
                        { name: 'hello' },
                        { name: 'wat' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
  {name: 'My tree 2'}
]
```

I was able to build a tree array with the following answer:
[PHP - create dynamic multidimensional file tree array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573821/7756724).

But the format seen in the Vue.js docs is more suitable for that case. I did not find a way to build the array without defining the directories as keys.

```
$fileTree = dir_tree('/xy');
return $fileTree;

function dir_tree($dir) {    
  $files = array_map('basename', glob("$dir/*"));
  foreach($files as $file) {
    if(is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
        $return[$file] = dir_tree("$dir/$file");
    } else {
        $return[] = [
            'name' => $file,
            'type' => explode('.', $file)[1]
        ];
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Which currently results to the following array:

```
{
  "folder1": {
    "0": {
        "name": "test1.txt",
        "type": "txt"
    },
    "child folder1": [
        {
            "name": "sample.png",
            "type": "png"
        }
    ]
  },
  "folder2": [
    {
        "name": "test2.txt",
        "type": "txt"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to manage that?

Comment: Please include your actual code you tried so far.

Comment: @04FS It is linked at the beginning of the question under the descirption "Tree View". I also added the array which I am referring to.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same code you mentioned in the question. And changing to the required structure.

**Note** using `json_encode` on both results will give the same output.

```
function dir_tree_array($dir) {
    $files = array_map('basename', glob("$dir/*"));
    $return = [];
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
            $return[] = [ "name"  =>  $file, "children" => dir_tree("$dir/$file")];
        } else {
            $return[] = ["name" => $file];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

function dir_tree_object($dir) {
        $files = array_map('basename', glob("$dir/*"));
        $return = [];
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if(is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $obj->name = $file;
                $obj->children = dir_tree("$dir/$file");
                $return[] = $obj;
            } else {
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $obj->name = $file;
                $return[] = $obj;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: Using this output with `json_encode` will give OP the desired result. Or if OP wants proper PHP objects, it can be manipulated accordingly.